# Whirlpool Duet parts identification

Tags: washing-machine

The bellows on my Whirlpool Duet washer has split and I need to order a new one. It is a model WFW9151YW. When I look it up, various web sites give me different parts numbers for this, AP6020669, PS11753988, and W10290499.

I suspect that these are all then same part, but with different brand names on them - AP for Amana?

In any event, does anyone know for sure if the W10290499 is the right part? That's the only one I can find on the 'web for sale in Canada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you believe everything you read on the innerwebs (which you shouldn't!!!), yes:

https://partsdr.com/part/w10381562-door-boot-seal/#model-WFW9151YW00